# How to display data in angular accordion differently for each accordion

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular accordion.  It will display accordions based on the object size in the (ng-repeat). When I click the Accordion Heading it should make an api call and store the result in a variable (department details) and it should be displayed in the Expanded window of the accordion.

When I click the first Accordion, it is making an API call and displaying data correctly in the Accordion window. But, When I click the second Accordion it is making an api call and now the data in both the accordions (first and second) are the same because the department details variable has the result of the second accordion api call.

How can I display the data unique to each accordion?. Should I make all api calls in controllers itself, store the results in an array, and use it in html instead of making api calls only when I click  Accordion-heading. Thanks in Advance.

HTML:

```
<accordion close-others="false">
    <accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-repeat="item in object">
        <accordion-heading">
            <span ng-click="Ctrl.getinfo(item.id)">
                {{item.label}}
            </span>
        </accordion-heading>
        <div> 
            {{Ctrl.departmentdetails}}
        </div>
     </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Controller:

```
public getinfo (departmentid): void {
    this.departmentdetails = null;
    this.services.getdepartmentdetails(departmentid).then((response):any=>{
        this.departmentdetails= response;
    });
}
```

Comment: Could we see the declaration of Ctrl.getinfo(item.id)  please ?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that Ctrl.departmentdetails is one string value that you use in each section of your ng-repeat. your current design just updates the value of one variable that gets repeated many times.  Ctrl.departmentdetails has little to do with your ng-repeat and that is your problem.  Right now you have the same string bound to many places in your view and when you do getinfo(), you are just updating that one string, which is then going to update it everywhere that it appears in your html.

your getinfo(item) function should take the item object and not just the id as an argument and then it will set departmentdetails on on the item object that you pass into it.  this would allow each item to have its own departmentdetails data.

you need to make getinfo() add a departmentdetails property to your item object when you make the api request, or else stick it in another array that you can use as a datasource for your view.

and change your html to something like this, or something that refers to the array of departmentdetails data that collects as your user expands each section.

```
<accordion close-others="false">
<accordion-group is-open="isopen" ng-repeat="item in object">
    <accordion-heading">
        <span ng-click="Ctrl.getinfo(item)">
            {{item.label}}
        </span>
    </accordion-heading>
    <div> 
        {{item.departmentdetails}}
    </div>
 </accordion-group>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ekill, Actually data is displaying correctly. But when i click second accordion it is making an api call and now departmentdetails property has second accordion result. Now, Even in the First accordion also it is showing second accordion results because i am using departmentsdetails property for every api call.

Comment: your template has one scope variable that has a string value that you are putting into the accordion body of everything in your ng-repeat.  you need to use item.departmentdetails in your template. does that make this clear? @mahesh

Comment: your template has one scope variable that has a string value that you are putting into the accordion body of everything in your ng-repeat.  you need to use item.departmentdetails in your template.  the function you have provided does make it look like you are properly setting this attribute on the item in the array, but your template is not referring to that property. does that help? @mahesh

Comment: Thanks @Ekill. departmentdetails contain the result of api call when i click {{item.label}}. Object is the array that i am using. there is no problem with ng-repeat.

Comment: @mahesh departmentdetails is one string variable that you are using inside of a view that gets repeated many times.  the same string value is going to show in each of your accordions because thats what you are telling it to do.  the problem is that you are referring to one single string value in your scope in every repeat.  every time your getinfo function is called that same string value is updated.  you need to use item.departmentdetails in your template not Ctrl.departmentdetails.

Comment: I just uploaded the picture. Could you please see it.

Comment: yes i can see it.  it is exactly as i imagined. @mahesh

Comment: departmentdetails variable is binded to controller. There will be no property called departmentdetails  in item object. Right now i am making an api call only when item.id is clicked. After api call success i am storing the result in departmentdetails variable.

Comment: @mahesh i have revised my answer for you again, i hope this makes sense to you now, i feel like you are starting to understand your problem